# Method for all objects that extend the same class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, java-8, extends

Let say I have 3 classes that all extend the same class...

```
public class Foo {
     private String name;
     ...
}
public class FooExtend1 extends Foo {
     ...
}
public class FooExtend2 extends Foo {
     ...
}
public class FooExtend3 extends Foo {
     ...
}
```

then I create a util function that changes the property that implements from Foo...

```
public void changeName(??? param1) {
     param1.setName("");
}
```

and I want param1 to be all objects that extends from the Foo class.

Would I have to overload the method or is there another way?

Comment: "*Would I have to overload the method [...]?*" - No. Rename `param1` to `a` and make it of type `Foo` and it will work as expected, given that `Foo` has a method `public void setName(String)`.

Comment: @Turing85 you should post an answer here

Comment: Do you have to do something different for each `FooExtendN` class?

Answer (score 3):

We do not need to override the method since the inheritance-relationship between the types grants the capabilites of implicit widening conversion from sub- to supertype (see [JLS, §5.1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5)). Thus, we can rewrite the method to

```
public void changeName(Foo param1) {
     param1.setName("");
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/DYQVLA) (I took the liberty and set the `name` in the utility method to `"foo"` so we can see that the method works in the demo output)

This works as expected, given that `Foo` has a method `public String setName(String)`.

---

A remark: I would suggest renaming method `changeName(...)` to something more expressive, e.g. `setEmptyName(...)` or `resetNameToDefault(...)`.

Comment: I even suggest to not create such method and access directly to `Foo.setName()`

Comment: @IQbrod that depends on the domain. Maybe some kind of (controlled) reset-functionality is useful, while the setter should not be exposed publicly. In those circumstances, such a method can be of use. If it should be placed in the object itself or in some kind of utility object is debatable.

Answer (score 0):

Your method defined in parent is accessible for all its children:

```java
public void changeName(String param1) {
     this.name = param1;
}
```

If you want to have method in some class outside:

```java
public void changeName(Foo foo, String newName) {
     foo.setName(newName);
}
```

and you can pass any Foo descendant there.